# Unable to connect to AWS RDS instance

Tags: mysql, firewall, amazon-web-services

I have set up a AWS RDS instance. I am using "end point" as hostname to establish the connection via MySQL workbench. But the connection is failing.

I am sitting behind a company firewall and as per [online](http://www.canyouseeme.org/) tools, port 3306, the port that I am using to for the connection is closed.

Can this be the reason why I am not being able to connect?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it would be.

To get to an RDS instance you need to have the instance in a security group that allows inbound access to port 3306 from whatever IP addresses you want to access it from, and your local access needs to allow port 3306 outbound to the RDS instance.

Comment: I get your first part- that the inbound traffic in the RDS shall come from pre specified machines. Though I am not clear on your second part. on my machine I guess only 3306 inbound is blocked and not 3306 outbound. How can I verify, whether inbound traffic is blocked or the outbound traffic is blocked?

Comment: @Smaxter The first step is to verify that the inbound rules on the RDS instance are set to allow you. Once you've done that, start working with your local network access to figure out how to get out.

Comment: i just checked back. I am using the default security group and it does not block any inbound or outbound traffic

Comment: @Smaxter Are you sure about that? By default, security groups block all traffic, and then you need to explicitly allow traffic you want to get through.