# AWS RDS to PgAdmin Error saving properties Unable to connect to server: timeout expired

Tags: amazon-web-services, postgresql, sql, amazon-rds

**Short description**: AWS RDS connecting server to [pgAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL#Database_administration) 4, PostgreSQL 11

**Done**: I have done similar [to this guy](https://youtu.be/0GpQJM7w6M8?t=215) or to [this AWS guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_GettingStarted.CreatingConnecting.PostgreSQL.html), but at the end when I click <kbd>Save</kbd>, it does not accept it for me. Instead it gives the following:

***Error***:

> Error saving properties 
> Unable to connect to server: 
> timeout expired

**What I have tried to solve the problem**:

- The instance is active, and it is two hours after creation
- I have also allowed to access the database with the outside of an AWS database client "YES"
- This Stack Overflow answer does not deliver results: *[AWS RDS PostgreSQL pgAdmin - Server doesn't listen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37901724/aws-rds-postgresql-pgadmin-server-doesnt-listen/37903485#37903485)*. Actually, after refreshing my security group like the guide says, my whole database disappeared
- I have home Wi-Fi, so there aren't any corporate firewalls or any of those issues: *[Unable to connect to AWS RDS instance](https://serverfault.com/questions/705312/unable-to-connect-to-aws-rds-instance)*
- while reading the previous Server Fault post, I looked up my
- RDS/Databases:  what was empty
- RDS/Security groups: empty and I have this message:

  > Your account does not support the EC2-Classic Platform in this region. DB Security Groups are only needed when the EC2-Classic Platform is supported. Instead, use VPC Security Groups to control access to your DB Instances.
- I have tried which this question: *[Unable to connect to public PostgreSQL RDS instance](https://serverfault.com/questions/656079/unable-to-connect-to-public-postgresql-rds-instance)* that had two good answers, but they gave the same error even after doing both of the changes
- *[Edward Q. Bridges's answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/656079/unable-to-connect-to-public-postgresql-rds-instance/656119#656119)*
- *[Abhash Kumar's answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/656079/unable-to-connect-to-public-postgresql-rds-instance/880710#880710)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit inbound rules

"Type" (left-most column) has to be turned to: all traffic and my IP address. Then it works.

[image]

Comment: Note: This should be done for the VPC security group your database is in. Just go to RDS console, then click on the database and then click on the database's VPC security group in the "Connectivity & security" tab.

Comment: The image is copied from [Edward Q. Bridges' answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/656079/unable-to-connect-to-public-postgresql-rds-instance/656119#656119) without attribution. Or in other words, it is [plagiarism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plagiarism#Noun).

Answer (score 1):

By default, **Public accessibility** is set to false while creating a database in AWS.

There are two options. Either to select it to true while creating the database or in case if you forgot to select it, you can modify the database and set it true.

1. While creating the database, **Additional connectivity configuration** section is collapsed and so it is difficult to notice this setting.

[image]

[image]

Expand the section **Additional connectivity configuration**, and you will find the setting to set "Publicly accessible" to Yes.

2. In case you already created the database, then you can modify the database and set the "Public accessibility" to "Yes".

Comment: the guide mentions that. And I have than it that ways. But I think your post is useful because as I read many people forgets that as well.